# change the background color of the cell to the value (and value another column) django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

```
class CourtColumn(tables.Column):
   def render(self, value):
      if value == 'Hard':
            self.attrs ={"td": {"bgcolor": "DeepSkyBlue"}}
      elif value == 'Clay':
            self.attrs ={"td": {"bgcolor": "SandyBrown"}}

class TodayTable(tables.Table):
   Rank  = tables.Column(accessor='tour.rank_t',orderable=True)
   Tour  = tables.Column(accessor='tour.name_t')
   Court = CourtColumn(accessor='tour.id_c_t.name_c',verbose_name= 'Court')
   ...
   def render_Tour(self, record):
      if record.tour.rank_t == 0:
            self.attrs ={"td": {"bgcolor": "Violet"}}
      return u"%s" % (record.tour.name_t)
```

I get to Court ... **td bgcolor="SandyBrown"** class="Court">Clay<  ... - ОК.How to get to the same Tour, but use the value of another column? def render_Tour not working as required

Answer (score 0):

Subclass tables.Column and take advantage of the record argument:

```
class TourColumn(tables.Column):
   def render(self, value, record):
      if record.tour.rank_t == 0:
        self.attrs ={"td": {"bgcolor": "Violet"}}
      return u"%s" % (record.tour.name_t)
```

Then use that class in your table:

```
Tour  = TourColumn(accessor='tour.name_t')
```